# Update Column while checking against a column with duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

I'm selecting my data with the following statement:

```
select distinct min(revision_number) as revno,po_number 
from PO_HEADER 
group by PO_NUMBER
having MIN(revision_number) > 0;
```

I get the following data:

```
7   30492-SA-EH504
20  30492-PS-SO895
20  30492-RA-DD219
26  30492-SA-KK474
1   30492-BA-AT236
17  30492-RA-DD386
21  30492-PS-FS803
25  30492-PS-WM324
33  30492-SA-NS011
```

I want to update the `MIN(REVISION_NUMBER)` to ZERO without changing any other values.  For example, `30492-SA-EH504` lists with the revisions as:

```
30492-SA-EH504 7
30492-SA-EH504 8
30492-SA-EH504 9
30492-SA-EH504 10
```

I only want to update the current min revision (7) to zero.  I tried this update query but it updated all of them to zero:

```
update PO_HEADER
set REVISION_NUMBER = '0'
from PO_HEADER
where exists (
select min(revision_number) as revno,po_number 
from PO_HEADER
group by PO_NUMBER
having MIN(revision_number) > 0
);
```

would select distinct help, or do I need something more intricate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way of solving it. You can actually update a common table expression:

```
with mins as (
  select po_number, revision_number
  from (
  select po_number, revision_number,
    row_number() over (partition by po_number order by revision_number) n
  from Table1
  ) A
  where A.n = 1
)
update mins set revision_number = 0

select * from Table1
```

**[SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b51d5/1)**

Comment: Great answer!  Additionally, thank you for that link to SQL Fiddle.  That's an amazing tool I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.  I prefer the one using the "IN" clause:

```
update PO_HEADER
    set REVISION_NUMBER = '0'
    where (po_header.Revision_NUMBER, po_header.po_number) in 
              (select min(revision_number) as revno, po_number
               from PO_HEADER
               group by PO_NUMBER
               having MIN(revision_number) > 0
              )
```

Your original query has no connection between the rows in the update table and the condition.  Hence, all evaluate to true, since the condition is true (rows exist).  I think the above syntax works in mysql -- looking for pairs using "IN".  If not, you can use the following:

```
update PO_HEADER
    set REVISION_NUMBER = '0'
    from (select min(revision_number) as revno, po_number
          from PO_HEADER
          group by PO_NUMBER
          having MIN(revision_number) > 0
         ) minr
    where po_header.Revision_NUMBER = minr.Revision_NUMBER and
         po_header.po_number = minr.po_number
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
UPDATE poh
  SET poh.RevisionNumber = 0
  FROM POHeader AS poh
  INNER JOIN (select distinct min(revision_number) as revno,po_number 
              from PO_HEADER 
              group by PO_NUMBER
              having MIN(revision_number) > 0) AS poh_rev
  ON poh.PO_Number = poh_rev.PO_Number And poh.RevisionNumber = poh_rev.revno
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update PO_HEADER
Set revision_number = 0
From (
      select distinct min(revision_number) as revno,po_number  
      from PO_HEADER
      group by PO_NUMBER 
      having MIN(revision_number) > 0
      )Z
Where PO_HEADER.revision_number = Z.revno
  and PO_HEADER.po_number = Z.po_number
```